# Как проверить, состоит ли строка из определенных символов?

Tags: c#, строки, комбинаторика

1. Пользователь вводит число неизвестной длины, например 6744.
2. Есть набор чисел (0..9999)
3. Из этого набора нужно исключить комбинации, состоящие из цифр введенного числа.  ( Т.е. 6, 4, 7, .... 4674, 7446, 4467 и др.)

Как это лучше сделать? Contains как по мне не канон в этом случае!
Может регулярки там или linq?

Comment: Не надо пробегаться от нуля до 9999: стоит найти distinc от цифр (4, 6, 7) и потом заняться всеми возможными перестановками этих цифр. Гм, как там? Точнее - выборкой с повторениями.

Comment: Просто мне матан задали и что-бы было с чем свериться, я хочу это накатать.
Я думал по быстрому накатать, но тут возникла проблема. Нужно пропустить нечетные числа, цифры которых совпадают с цифрами числа на входе. 
Т.е. повторять 4226 и 4226, просто меняя местами двойки не допускается.
А на счет вашего предложения, я как понимаю вы хотели написать метод .Distinct()? Который убирает повторяющиеся символы? И как мне потом все числа перекомбинировать?

Comment: Он уже есть в linq, можете просто посмотреть вывод `"6744".ToCharArray().Distinct()`

Answer (score 2):

Можно как то так попробовать:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var nums = new int[] { 6, 7, 4, 4 };
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        foreach (var permutation in Permutations<int>.AllFor(nums))
        {
            var f = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", permutation));
            result.Add(f);
        }
        
        var withMissed = result.Where(x => x != 4674 && x != 7446 && x != 4467).ToList();
        
        result.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        Console.WriteLine("----------");
        withMissed.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    }
}

public class Permutations<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> AllFor(T[] array)
    {
        if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
        {
            yield return new T[0];
        }
        else
        {
            for (int pick = 0; pick < array.Length; ++pick)
            {
                T item = array[pick];
                int i = -1;
                T[] rest = Array.FindAll<T>(
                    array, delegate(T p) { return ++i != pick; }
                );
                foreach (T[] restPermuted in AllFor(rest))
                {
                    i = -1;
                    yield return Array.ConvertAll<T, T>(
                        array,
                        delegate(T p)
                        {
                            return ++i == 0 ? item : restPermuted[i - 1];
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Перебор 0-9999 ломается об колено пунктом `неизвестной длины`. Пятизначное число уже не сработает. По мимо того, что он невероятно грузный.

Нужно использовать рекурсию.

Ввели `123`. Всего шесть вариантов:

```
          ...
    /      |      \
  1..     2..     3..
  / \     / \     / \
12. 13. 21. 23. 32. 31.
 |   |   |   |   |   |
123 132 213 231 321 312
```

Конструируем строки перебором индексов, удаляя использованные. А затем проверив, есть ли в `InputNumber` одинаковые цифры, использовать `Distinct`, поскольку если совпадений нет, это операция лишняя и грузная с большими цифрами.

```
string InputNumber;
// если число из одной цифры всё совсем просто
if (InputNumber.Length == 1)
    return new[] { int.Parse(InputNumber) };

List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
Generator(numbers, InputNumber);

// Проверка на одинаковые символы
List<char> CharsOfNumbers = new List<char>(InputNumber.ToCharArray());
CharsOfNumbers.Distinct();

if (CharsOfNumbers.Count != InputNumber.Length)
    numbers.Distinct();

return numbers.ToArray();
```

Рекурсивный метод:

```
private void Generator (List<int> resultNumbers, string number, string result = "") {
    if (number.Length < 2)
        resultNumbers.Add(int.Parse(result+number));
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++) {
            string NewResult = result+number[i].ToString(); // Генерируемое число
            string NewNumber = number.Remove(i, 1); // Неиспользованные числа
            Generator(resultNumbers, NewNumber, NewResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Код не тестил, но все должно пахать.

Все просто максимально деревяно.

```
Int number = 6744;

var symbols = number.ToString()
                    .ToCharArray()
                    .Distinct();

var exceptions = Enumerable
                    .Range     (1, 4) // макс число 9999 - значит числа не более 4 символов
                    .Select    ( a => symbols.DifferentCombinations(a) )
                    .SelectMany( b => Int32.Parse(new string(b)) );

var result = Enumerable
                    .Range(0, 9999)
                    .Except(exceptions);
```

extension:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> DifferentCombinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
    {
        return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
          elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
            elements.Skip(i + 1).DifferentCombinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] {e}).Concat(c)));
    }
}
```

Экстеншн скомуниздил отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336576/4423545

Код писал из головы без вижуалки, поэтому могут быть синтаксические ошибки. Исправишь сам.

---

Можно ли сделать код быстрее? Можно. Но код будет запутанным и с большей вероятностью с ошибками. Лично я предпочитаю писать более простой и понятный код, чем оптимальный по скорости. А скорость оптимизировать уже по мере необходимости.

Наверняка код Yaroslav (через yield ) окажется быстрее. Но практически наверняка там есть ошибки которые прийдется долго искать и дебажить) При "деревяном" же подходе ошибиться сложно, а ошибки исправлять очень просто, даже, если они есть.

Comment: Мммм... У вас b надо к строке привести из `IEnumerable<char>`: `SelectMany( b => Int32.Parse(new string(b)) );`